# CMD Print command recognize corrupted files

Tags: windows, powershell, pdf, cmd.exe, printer

I print pdfs using CMD and it sends corrupted pdfs just like working ones. I would like to know if there is a way to filter corrupted ones and only print those that actually work.

I currently use `Print /d:[PrinterName] [FilePath]`

Are there alternative CMD commands / Powershell commands or do I have to use a response from the printer?

Comment: Print just sends the file to the printer so if your printer has not the capability to interpret PDF files that will not work (only larger office laser printers usually may have this ability, especially when it supports printing from USB stick without computer). Or may be the PDF files use different PDF versions and your printer only supports older PDF versions.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought. The Printer can interpret PDF files it's just that some are formated wrong or something so it results in endless pages of gibberish. Anyways I found a workaround using acrobat to check the files, so if they are totaly corrupted acrobat will catch them. Maybe I can get the printer to check them though.